# Assign column-count property based on content size (CSS issue)

Tags: css

I have some paragraphs in my page. Some are very lengthy while some are very small. I have given common property of `column-count : 2` for all the paragraph. But the problem is I **don't want to split the paragraph into two if the content is just two or three lines only**

Here is my code.

```css
p{
 column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<h2>First paragraph (needs to be two column)</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<h2>Second one (no need of column)</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the </p>
```

Here my **first** paragraph is lengthy and **I want that to be shown as two columns**.
But my **second** paragraph is too small and **I don't want** that to be in two columns.

Here is a **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxcvkzmv/)** of minimal working code.

Note: I can't predict which paragraph will be lengthy, which one will be small. It's coming from the server.

**Edit**: Since I'm having more than 100 paragraphs in my actual code, I prefer to resolve this using CSS only (If possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do this with JavasScript. CSS cannot be conditionally enabled or disabled based on the word count of the content it's styling.

Of course, it doesn't have to be JS on the client. You could add the class `short-paragraph` on your server too.

#### JS

```
function letterCount(element) {
    return element.textContent.length;
}

function isShort(element) {
    return letterCount(element) < 200;
}

Array.prototype.slice
    .call(document.getElementsByTagName('p')).forEach(paragraph => {
        if (isShort(paragraph)) {
            paragraph.classList.add('short-paragraph')
        }
    });
```

#### CSS

```
p {
    column-count: 2;
}

p.short-paragraph {
  column-count: 1;
}
```

Here's a [working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/935wztao/).

### Speed

Based on OP' reply, speed might be an issue. Here's a quick [benchmark](https://jsfiddle.net/ocd9st0y/) with 500 paragraphs (check the console). My old laptop makes it in 5ms, so it should not be an issue.

Comment: So do i need to find the `innertext` length of all the paragraphs and add class to them based on the length using javascript?

Comment: Yes, you can have `short-paragraph` class which you add with JS if the text is, for example, less than 100 characters. The `short-paragraph` class will have `column-count` set to `1`.

Comment: Thanx lazar. But my problem is there are more than 100 paragraph. Iterating over 100 paragraphs is a pain. Let me see whether there is a solution with CSS only. If not, then I will do this and will accept your answer for sure

Comment: You could do this on the server too, instead of client-side.

Comment: @SyamPillai I don't think this is too expensive. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ocd9st0y/) with a benchmark of 500 paragraphs. Check the console to see how long it takes on your computer. It takes 5ms on my laptop from 6 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.odd {
  column-count: 1;
}
.even {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<h2>First paragraph (needs to be two column)</h2>
<p class="even">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<h2>Second one (no need of column)</h2>
<p class="odd">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the </p>
```

Nice and simple, Create an odd and even class for your paragraphs and then style to your liking. Whichever Paragraphs you dont want to have two columns just assign them the odd class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I can't predict which paragraph is small and which one will be big

Comment: OP said he can't predict which paragraph will be lenghty so manually adding `even` and `odd` (which are very misguiding names, by the way) won't work for the OP's usecase.

Comment: Well scrap this then, Just seen your Note, that you can't predict what your paragraph size will be so yes go with @Lazar answer.